# Tab not working in python 3.6, working in 3.5, 3.6 32 bit version on Windows

Tags: python, cmd

I have a few versions of python installed on my computer. The default launched when I type py into windows command prompt is:

> Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

When I hit tab I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py",
>   line 768, in hook_wrapper_23
>       res = ensure_str(readline_hook(prompt))   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py",
>   line 571, in readline
>       self._readline_from_keyboard()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py",
>   line 536, in _readline_from_keyboard
>       if self._readline_from_keyboard_poll():   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py",
>   line 556, in _readline_from_eyboard_poll
>       result = self.mode.process_keyevent(event.keyinfo)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py",
>   line 243, in process_keyevent
>       r = self.process_keyevent_queue-1   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py",
>   line 286, in _process_keyevent
>       r = dispatch_func(keyinfo)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py",
>   line 257, in complete
>       completions = self._get_completions()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py",
>   line 200, in _get_completions
>       r = self.completer(ensure_unicode(text), i)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\rlcompleter.py",
>   line 80, in complete
>       readline.redisplay() AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute 'redisplay'

This same error doesn't occur when I launch a different python version.

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python.exe
>   Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32
>   bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license"
>   for more information.
>
> >>>

What's going on here? I'd like to be able to use tab again in my normal python version. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's an issue with pyreadline : https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline/issues/49