# Python hitting tab fails with Python AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute 'redisplay'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, readline

Using Python 3.7.3 (Anaconda) on Windows, hitting tab results in the following traceback:

```
Readline internal error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py", line 768, in hook_wrapper_23
    res = ensure_str(readline_hook(prompt))
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 571, in readline
    self._readline_from_keyboard()
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 536, in _readline_from_keyboard
    if self._readline_from_keyboard_poll():
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 556, in _readline_from_keyboard_poll
    result = self.mode.process_keyevent(event.keyinfo)
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 243, in process_keyevent
    r = self.process_keyevent_queue[-1](keyinfo)
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 286, in _process_keyevent
    r = dispatch_func(keyinfo)
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 257, in complete
    completions = self._get_completions()
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 200, in _get_completions
    r = self.completer(ensure_unicode(text), i)
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\rlcompleter.py", line 80, in complete
    readline.redisplay()
AttributeError: module 'readline' has no attribute 'redisplay'
```

Environment details:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Python 3.7.3, Anaconda distribution
- pyreadline == 2.1
- Tab key works fine in IPython

I am aware pyreadline is likely causing the issue. [Tab not working in python 3.6, working in 3.5, 3.6 32 bit version on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727386/tab-not-working-in-python-3-6-working-in-3-5-3-6-32-bit-version-on-windows) suggests uninstalling pyreadline. However, when I try `pip uninstall pyreadline` I get this error:

```
Cannot uninstall 'pyreadline'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Trying this also did not help: [Unable to install 'pyreadline' using pip on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261584/unable-to-install-pyreadline-using-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Anaconda module **readline** is different from the standard Python [readline](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/readline.html#module-readline) which does have the method redisplay. The workaround I found to make this work was disabling the autocomplete. To archive that you need to set as True the attribute **disable_readline** in the file **rlmain.py** line 58.

> ..\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py

```
class BaseReadline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.allow_ctrl_c = False
        self.ctrl_c_tap_time_interval = 0.3

        self.debug = False
        self.bell_style = 'none'
        self.mark = -1
        self.console=MockConsole()
        self.disable_readline = True # Old value: False
```

Comment: Very interesting... unfortunately I don't have the machine where this was an issue, but seems like a plausible solution so I will upvote. If others do the same I will accept

Comment: @wkzhu I can confirm that this works. Thanks Miguel!

Comment: Worked for me, why isn't this True by default?

Comment: It works to bring back the 'tab' key, but then I lose the auto-completion feature of the 'tab' key...Still, I up-voted this answer.